# How to launch the julia interpreter with arguments in juno?

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

How can I launch the julia interpreter with arguments (-p 4 for workers), in the juno plugin for atom?

For example in the command line, you call:

`julia -p 4`

and you start the julia interpreter with 4 workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer how to do it in Juno, but a general hint: you can also manage the workers within a Julia process. Here is an example within the REPL

```
julia> addprocs(4)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> rmprocs(2)
:ok

julia> workers()
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4
 5
```

Comment: nice one--i was trying to use addprocs_local, which i thought i had taken directly from the julia source

Answer (score 0):

Simple execute in the console: `;julia -p 4`